# How do I get picture link instead of download link in facebook graph v17.0?

Tags: go, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I use golang with golang.org/x/oauth2/facebook
I try to get picture link but when I click link. It download file. How do I get picturelink from graph api?

I've try this
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,picture.width(500).height(500)&access_token=mytoken`

and use id get from this
`https://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=square&redirect=false`
but when I click picture link. It's get default profile picture. Not my profile that login with oauth.

Comment: In most situations, you need to add an access token to get the real user profile image, and not just the silhouette, all explained under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: _"but when I click link. It download file"_ - Facebook responds with a header that makes the browser show the download dialog, when the URL gets requested directly. If you use it as the `src` of an image element, it should work fine though.

Comment: Thanks. I am just afraid it might be not working the same way. I've checked out and stored file in my server. The picture link and picture download link work the same way. Thank you again.